# Optimising group by on self referential join with millions of rows

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

I have a table (actually materialized view) with millions of rows. Schema is something like:

```
id
correlation_id
name
```

I want to be able to determine, which ids appear together, and how many times. For example, given the rows:

```
id, correlation_id, name
1,       1,         'foo',
2,       1,         'bar',
3,       2,         'baz'
1,       2,         'foo'
2,       2,         'bar'
```

I want to get something like

```
id1, id2, count
1,    2,    2
1,    3,    1
2,    1,    2
2,    3,    1
3,    1,    1
3,    2,    1
```

To explain, `foo` is with `bar` across 2 different correlation ids. But is with `baz` in only one correlation id.

My naive implementation is this:

```
SELECT f1.id, f2.id, COUNT(f2.id)
FROM foo f1
INNER JOIN foo f2 ON f1.correlation_id = f2.correlation_id AND f1.id <> f2.id
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Problem is, it results in a very expensive sort. The explain query looks like this:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=546688884.02..569757450.38 rows=272085025 width=38)
  Group Key: f1.id, f2.id
  ->  Sort  (cost=546688884.02..551775813.05 rows=2034771611 width=30)
        Sort Key: f1.id, f2.id
        ->  Merge Join  (cost=1.12..37356601.80 rows=2034771611 width=30)
              Merge Cond: (f1.correlation_id = f2.correlation_id)
              Join Filter: (f1.id <> f2.id)
              ->  Index Only Scan using foo_id_correlation_id on entities f1  (cost=0.56..823407.15 rows=20284706 width=31)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.56..874118.92 rows=20284706 width=31)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using foo_id_correlation_id on entities f2  (cost=0.56..823407.15 rows=20284706 width=31)
```

I've tried 3 different indexes (one you're seeing in the example above):

An index on `id`

An index on `correlation_id`

A sorted index on `id` and `correlation_id` (i.e. `(id ASC, correlation_id ASC)`)

None of them really had any affect on the final cost, the sort always seems to be needed.

Slightly at a loss as to what is the best way to index my data to make this query inexpensive to run. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please tag your postgres version.

Comment: @McNets, apologies, done.

Comment: Can you try after adding an index on `(correlation_id, id)` ?

Comment: Also: how big is the table? How much RAM does the server have? And what are your `shared_buffers` and `work_mem` settings?

Comment: Consider instructions in the [\[postgresql-performance\] tag info](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).